# Rearrange eye tracking data

Tags: r, csv

I have an eye tracking data file which I need to transform. Let me explain, my data are formatted like this:

```
Event; Info; PS;Modulo
MSG; start_consigne; nan;
EFI; L; 904.0;
EFI; L; 906.0;
EFI; L; 838.0;
EFI; L; 805.0;
EFI; L; 789.0;
EFI; L; 797.0;
EFI; L; 876.0;
EFI; L; 924.0;
EFI; L; 928.0;
EFI; L; 964.0;
EFI; L; 957.0;
EFI; L; 935.0;
EFI; L; 861.0;
EFI; L; 834.0;
EFI; L; 856.0;
EFI; L; 846.0;
EFI; L; 811.0;
EFI; L; 825.0;
EFI; L; 869.0;
EFI; L; 904.0;
EFI; L; 936.0;
EFI; L; 969.0;
EFI; L; 965.0;
EFI; L; 1016.0;
EFI; L; 1018.0;
EFI; L; 1030.0;
EFI; L; 1015.0;
EFI; L; 999.0;
EFI; L; 987.0;
EFI; L; 1017.0;
EFI; L; 1064.0;
EFI; L; 1080.0;
EFI; L; 1061.0;
EFI; L; 1075.0;
EFI; L; 1046.0;
EFI; L; 1005.0;
EFI; L; 1014.0;
EFI; L; 1023.0;
EFI; L; 1040.0;
EFI; L; 1051.0;
EFI; L; 1046.0;
EFI; L; 1010.0;
EFI; L; 971.0;
EFI; L; 994.0;
EFI; L; 1071.0;
EFI; L; 1082.0;
EFI; L; 1120.0;
EFI; L; 1119.0;
EFI; L; 1044.0;
EFI; L; 1023.0;
EFI; L; 978.0;
EFI; L; 947.0;
EFI; L; 925.0;
EFI; L; 900.0;
EFI; L; 940.0;
MSG; stop_consigne; nan;
EFI; L; 963.0;
MSG; start_trial_0; nan;
EFI; L; 995.0;
EFI; L; 1013.0;
EFI; L; 1046.0;
EFI; L; 1005.0;
EFI; L; 1013.0;
EFI; L; 1043.0;
EFI; L; 1146.0;
EFI; L; 1205.0;
MSG; id_1129; nan;
MSG; 36=32mod4; nan;36=32mod4
MSG; val_1; nan;
MSG; correct_1; nan;
MSG; RT_2241; nan;
MSG; difficulty_Very; nan;
MSG; strat_4; nan;
MSG; stop_trial_0; nan;
MSG; start_trial_1; nan;
EFI; L; 1306.0;
EFI; L; 1334.0;
EFI; L; 1285.0;
EFI; L; 1297.0;
EFI; L; 1257.0;
EFI; L; 1206.0;
EFI; L; 1206.0;
EFI; L; 1256.0;
EFI; L; 1252.0;
EFI; L; 1189.0;
EFI; L; 1254.0;
EFI; L; 1214.0;
EFI; L; 1203.0;
EFI; L; 1207.0;
EFI; L; 1263.0;
EFI; L; 1224.0;
EFI; L; 1235.0;
EFI; L; 1258.0;
EFI; L; 1210.0;
EFI; L; 1186.0;
EFI; L; 1201.0;
EFI; L; 1271.0;
EFI; L; 1246.0;
EFI; L; 1274.0;
EFI; L; 1337.0;
EFI; L; 1325.0;
EFI; L; 1551.0;
EFI; L; 1733.0;
EFI; L; 1812.0;
EFI; L; 1568.0;
MSG; id_4333; nan;
MSG; modulo_58; nan;58=52mod4
MSG; val_0; nan;
MSG; correct_1; nan;
MSG; RT_14182; nan;
MSG; difficulty_Very; nan;
MSG; strat_4; nan;
MSG; stop_trial_1; nan;
MSG; start_trial_2; nan;
EFI; L; 1272.0;
EFI; L; 1218.0;
EFI; L; 1227.0;
EFI; L; 1165.0;
EFI; L; 1145.0;
EFI; L; 1192.0;
EFI; L; 1199.0;
EFI; L; 1208.0;
EFI; L; 1248.0;
EFI; L; 1280.0;
EFI; L; 1224.0;
MSG; id_6016; nan;
MSG; modulo_66; nan;66=61mod6
MSG; val_0; nan;
MSG; correct_1; nan;
MSG; RT_3727; nan;
MSG; difficulty_Very; nan;
MSG; strat_1; nan;
MSG; stop_trial_2; nan;
EFI; L; 1220.0;
MSG; start_trial_3; nan;
EFI; L; 1229.0;
EFI; L; 1250.0;
EFI; L; 1372.0;
EFI; L; 1102.0;
MSG; id_15693; nan;
MSG; modulo_99; nan;99=93mod6
MSG; val_1; nan;
MSG; correct_1; nan;
MSG; RT_2624; nan;
MSG; difficulty_Very; nan;
MSG; strat_1; nan;
MSG; stop_trial_3; nan;
MSG; start_trial_4; nan;
```

Knowing that, I never have the same number of "Fixation" line for each trial.

I want my data to be like that:

```
Trial_0; ACC_0; RT_850; Fixation; L; 1020
Trial_0; ACC_0; RT_850; Fixation; L; 1200
Trial_0; ACC_0; RT_850; Fixation; L; 980
Trial_0; ACC_0; RT_850; Fixation; L; 990
Trial_0; ACC_0; RT_850; Fixation; L; 1003
Trial_1; ACC_1; RT_920; Fixation; L; 1023
Trial_1; ACC_1; RT_920; Fixation; L; 1020
Trial_1; ACC_1; RT_920; Fixation; L; 997
Trial_1; ACC_1; RT_920; Fixation; L; 1123
```

As I'm not an experimented R user, I absolutely don't know how to do that (if it's possible). And as my data file contain over 1000000 lines, it cannot be done manually.

I only have one ACC and one RT code per trial as it represent the accuracy and the response time of this trial. I have a 2000 Hz eye tracker that's why I have such a big file.

```
structure(list(Event = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("EFI", 
"MSG"), class = "factor"), Info = structure(c(127L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 172L, 51L, 128L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
11L, 1L, 220L, 3L, 95L, 7L, 218L, 173L, 129L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 35L, 61L, 219L, 3L, 86L, 7L, 218L, 174L, 140L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 41L, 66L, 219L, 
3L, 107L, 7L, 216L, 185L, 51L, 151L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 27L, 
83L, 220L, 3L, 98L, 7L, 216L, 196L, 162L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 30L, 57L, 219L, 3L, 88L, 7L, 217L, 207L, 167L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 36L, 62L, 220L, 3L, 93L, 7L, 217L, 211L, 
168L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 48L, 71L, 219L, 3L, 85L, 7L, 216L, 
212L, 169L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 26L, 83L, 
220L, 3L, 102L, 7L, 216L, 213L, 170L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 29L, 56L, 220L, 3L, 101L, 4L, 218L, 214L, 51L, 171L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 49L, 72L, 220L, 2L, 103L, 
4L, 216L, 215L, 130L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 20L, 80L, 219L, 3L, 116L, 4L, 218L, 175L, 131L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 25L, 83L, 219L, 3L, 125L, 4L, 216L, 176L, 132L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 32L, 52L, 219L, 3L, 126L, 4L, 218L, 
177L, 133L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 8L, 
53L, 220L, 3L, 97L, 4L, 218L, 178L, 134L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 40L, 65L, 219L, 
3L, 117L, 4L, 216L, 179L, 135L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 9L, 74L, 220L, 
3L, 121L, 4L, 216L, 180L, 136L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 28L, 55L, 220L, 3L, 84L, 6L, 218L, 181L, 137L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 31L, 58L, 219L, 3L, 112L, 6L, 218L, 
182L, 138L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 45L, 69L, 219L, 3L, 120L, 6L, 216L, 
183L, 139L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 46L, 70L, 220L, 2L, 90L, 6L, 216L, 184L, 141L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 37L, 63L, 
219L, 3L, 114L, 6L, 216L, 186L, 142L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 39L, 65L, 220L, 3L, 100L, 6L, 216L, 187L, 143L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 21L, 81L, 220L, 
2L, 89L, 6L, 217L, 188L, 144L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 22L, 82L, 220L, 3L, 106L, 6L, 217L, 189L, 145L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 33L, 59L, 219L, 
3L, 110L, 5L, 216L, 190L, 146L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 44L, 68L, 220L, 3L, 99L, 5L, 216L, 191L, 147L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 50L, 73L, 220L, 3L, 91L, 5L, 218L, 192L, 
148L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 10L, 75L, 219L, 2L, 115L, 5L, 218L, 193L, 149L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 38L, 64L, 220L, 3L, 124L, 5L, 218L, 194L, 150L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 14L, 76L, 220L, 3L, 94L, 5L, 216L, 195L, 
152L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 15L, 77L, 219L, 3L, 118L, 5L, 218L, 197L, 153L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 18L, 79L, 219L, 3L, 122L, 5L, 216L, 198L, 154L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 34L, 60L, 220L, 3L, 119L, 7L, 216L, 199L, 155L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 42L, 67L, 220L, 
3L, 108L, 7L, 218L, 200L, 51L, 156L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
43L, 68L, 219L, 3L, 96L, 7L, 216L, 201L, 157L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 19L, 80L, 219L, 
3L, 123L, 7L, 218L, 202L, 158L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 12L, 76L, 219L, 3L, 111L, 7L, 217L, 203L, 159L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 13L, 76L, 220L, 
3L, 113L, 7L, 217L, 204L, 160L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 16L, 78L, 220L, 2L, 104L, 7L, 216L, 205L, 161L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 17L, 79L, 219L, 
3L, 109L, 7L, 216L, 206L, 163L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 23L, 54L, 219L, 3L, 105L, 7L, 216L, 208L, 51L, 164L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 24L, 54L, 220L, 3L, 92L, 7L, 217L, 209L, 
165L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 47L, 70L, 
220L, 3L, 87L, 7L, 217L, 210L, 166L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L), .Label = c("36=32mod4", "correct_0", 
"correct_1", "difficulty_Easy", "difficulty_Hard", "difficulty_Intermediate", 
"difficulty_Very", "id_1058", "id_10975", "id_11207", "id_1129", 
"id_12052", "id_12069", "id_12131", "id_12453", "id_13285", "id_13741", 
"id_13817", "id_14467", "id_14596", "id_14907", "id_15262", "id_1544", 
"id_1555", "id_15661", "id_15684", "id_15693", "id_1685", "id_2295", 
"id_2479", "id_2820", "id_313", "id_3645", "id_3985", "id_4333", 
"id_4541", "id_5249", "id_5426", "id_5684", "id_5756", "id_6016", 
"id_6326", "id_7019", "id_7064", "id_7885", "id_8660", "id_8728", 
"id_9028", "id_9263", "id_9419", "L", "modulo_26", "modulo_36", 
"modulo_40", "modulo_42", "modulo_46", "modulo_47", "modulo_50", 
"modulo_55", "modulo_57", "modulo_58", "modulo_59", "modulo_63", 
"modulo_64", "modulo_65", "modulo_66", "modulo_68", "modulo_71", 
"modulo_74", "modulo_77", "modulo_78", "modulo_79", "modulo_80", 
"modulo_85", "modulo_86", "modulo_89", "modulo_90", "modulo_93", 
"modulo_94", "modulo_96", "modulo_97", "modulo_98", "modulo_99", 
"RT_10590", "RT_1367", "RT_14182", "RT_15412", "RT_1550", "RT_17151", 
"RT_17302", "RT_1736", "RT_1891", "RT_2002", "RT_2227", "RT_2241", 
"RT_2432", "RT_2510", "RT_2624", "RT_2660", "RT_2840", "RT_2956", 
"RT_2984", "RT_3029", "RT_3154", "RT_3273", "RT_3283", "RT_3727", 
"RT_3900", "RT_4493", "RT_4544", "RT_4840", "RT_5095", "RT_5368", 
"RT_5583", "RT_5618", "RT_6009", "RT_6385", "RT_6423", "RT_6489", 
"RT_6689", "RT_7471", "RT_7669", "RT_7697", "RT_8156", "RT_8752", 
"RT_8784", "start_consigne", "start_trial_0", "start_trial_1", 
"start_trial_10", "start_trial_11", "start_trial_12", "start_trial_13", 
"start_trial_14", "start_trial_15", "start_trial_16", "start_trial_17", 
"start_trial_18", "start_trial_19", "start_trial_2", "start_trial_20", 
"start_trial_21", "start_trial_22", "start_trial_23", "start_trial_24", 
"start_trial_25", "start_trial_26", "start_trial_27", "start_trial_28", 
"start_trial_29", "start_trial_3", "start_trial_30", "start_trial_31", 
"start_trial_32", "start_trial_33", "start_trial_34", "start_trial_35", 
"start_trial_36", "start_trial_37", "start_trial_38", "start_trial_39", 
"start_trial_4", "start_trial_40", "start_trial_41", "start_trial_42", 
"start_trial_43", "start_trial_5", "start_trial_6", "start_trial_7", 
"start_trial_8", "start_trial_9", "stop_consigne", "stop_trial_0", 
"stop_trial_1", "stop_trial_10", "stop_trial_11", "stop_trial_12", 
"stop_trial_13", "stop_trial_14", "stop_trial_15", "stop_trial_16", 
"stop_trial_17", "stop_trial_18", "stop_trial_19", "stop_trial_2", 
"stop_trial_20", "stop_trial_21", "stop_trial_22", "stop_trial_23", 
"stop_trial_24", "stop_trial_25", "stop_trial_26", "stop_trial_27", 
"stop_trial_28", "stop_trial_29", "stop_trial_3", "stop_trial_30", 
"stop_trial_31", "stop_trial_32", "stop_trial_33", "stop_trial_34", 
"stop_trial_35", "stop_trial_36", "stop_trial_37", "stop_trial_38", 
"stop_trial_39", "stop_trial_4", "stop_trial_40", "stop_trial_41", 
"stop_trial_42", "stop_trial_5", "stop_trial_6", "stop_trial_7", 
"stop_trial_8", "stop_trial_9", "strat_1", "strat_2", "strat_4", 
"val_0", "val_1"), class = "factor"), PS = c(NA, 904L, 906L, 
838L, 805L, 789L, 797L, 876L, 924L, 928L, 964L, 957L, 935L, 861L, 
834L, 856L, 846L, 811L, 825L, 869L, 904L, 936L, 969L, 965L, 1016L, 
1018L, 1030L, 1015L, 999L, 987L, 1017L, 1064L, 1080L, 1061L, 
1075L, 1046L, 1005L, 1014L, 1023L, 1040L, 1051L, 1046L, 1010L, 
971L, 994L, 1071L, 1082L, 1120L, 1119L, 1044L, 1023L, 978L, 947L, 
925L, 900L, 940L, NA, 963L, NA, 995L, 1013L, 1046L, 1005L, 1013L, 
1043L, 1146L, 1205L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1306L, 
1334L, 1285L, 1297L, 1257L, 1206L, 1206L, 1256L, 1252L, 1189L, 
1254L, 1214L, 1203L, 1207L, 1263L, 1224L, 1235L, 1258L, 1210L, 
1186L, 1201L, 1271L, 1246L, 1274L, 1337L, 1325L, 1551L, 1733L, 
1812L, 1568L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1272L, 1218L, 
1227L, 1165L, 1145L, 1192L, 1199L, 1208L, 1248L, 1280L, 1224L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1220L, NA, 1229L, 1250L, 1372L, 
1102L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1141L, 1163L, 1146L, 
1129L, 1190L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1182L, 1152L, 
1134L, 1179L, 1178L, 1267L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1272L, 1186L, 1164L, 1173L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1265L, 1191L, 1109L, 1150L, 1125L, 1090L, 1139L, 1205L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1277L, 1164L, 1122L, 1113L, 1115L, 
1121L, 1168L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1235L, NA, 1207L, 
1164L, 1145L, 1177L, 1242L, 1224L, 1281L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1234L, 1232L, 1204L, 1198L, 1108L, 1131L, 1220L, 
1228L, 1227L, 1231L, 1299L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1211L, 1266L, 1294L, 1292L, 1129L, 1182L, 1175L, 1211L, 1233L, 
1206L, 1185L, 1307L, 1209L, 1206L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1245L, 1264L, 1283L, 1246L, 1290L, 1344L, 1311L, 1267L, 
1201L, 1188L, 1164L, 1218L, 1188L, 1156L, 1144L, 1121L, 1145L, 
1176L, 1155L, 1103L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1173L, 
1223L, 1218L, 1170L, 1120L, 1084L, 1096L, 1092L, 985L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1043L, 1092L, 1090L, 1126L, 1099L, 
1125L, 1175L, 1099L, 1102L, 1188L, 1215L, 1225L, 1197L, 1268L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1292L, 1338L, 1322L, 1284L, 
1296L, 1273L, 1251L, 1216L, 1205L, 1200L, 1165L, 1097L, 1132L, 
1209L, 1243L, 1295L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1288L, 
1286L, 1243L, 1245L, 1215L, 1213L, 1215L, 1283L, 1280L, 1275L, 
1334L, 1301L, 1205L, 1215L, 1267L, 1245L, 1203L, 1071L, 1113L, 
1160L, 1211L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1243L, 1249L, 
1268L, 1266L, 1299L, 1363L, 1215L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 938L, 831L, 929L, 999L, 1033L, 1090L, 1092L, 1094L, 1139L, 
1144L, 1225L, 1203L, 1199L, 1261L, 1221L, 1230L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1291L, 1308L, 1270L, 1250L, 1276L, 1226L, 
1197L, 1201L, 1213L, 1195L, 1202L, 1201L, 1194L, 1192L, 1190L, 
1206L, 1244L, 1203L, 1228L, 1239L, 1218L, 1218L, 1217L, 1218L, 
1202L, 1224L, 1177L, 1134L, 1134L, 1152L, 1159L, 1162L, 1168L, 
1107L, 1175L, 1200L, 1173L, 1203L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1266L, 1278L, 1227L, 1188L, 1184L, 1178L, 1167L, 1194L, 
1131L, 1166L, 1203L, 1211L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1223L, 1226L, 1218L, 1208L, 1142L, 1105L, 1122L, 1156L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1118L, 1133L, 1150L, 1115L, 1070L, 
1078L, 1145L, 1156L, 1175L, 1172L, 1129L, 1134L, 1089L, 1144L, 
1171L, 1179L, 1195L, 1194L, 1231L, 1275L, 1250L, 1273L, 1268L, 
1221L, 1245L, 1211L, 1195L, 1197L, 1194L, 1140L, 1168L, 1220L, 
1197L, 1191L, 1240L, 1288L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1339L, 1327L, 1324L, 1320L, 1242L, 1231L, 1253L, 1255L, 1268L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1297L, 1303L, 1282L, 1252L, 
1200L, 1202L, 1191L, 1177L, 1220L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1221L, 1224L, 1203L, 1162L, 1175L, 1187L, 1184L, 1165L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1200L, 1225L, 1200L, 1205L, 
1219L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1269L, 1209L, 1161L, 
1171L, 1165L, 1140L, 1120L, 1127L, 1076L, 1081L, 1081L, 1114L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1181L, 1186L, 1189L, 1200L, 
1179L, 1186L, 1171L, 1134L, 1012L, 1004L, 1134L, 1090L, 1146L, 
1222L, 1309L, 1334L, 1354L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1240L, 1121L, 1101L, 1104L, 1142L, 1157L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1197L, 1264L, 1217L, 1181L, 1173L, 1160L, 1147L, 
1174L, 1188L, 1183L, 1162L, 1188L, 1273L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1303L, 1335L, 1346L, 1284L, 1227L, 1245L, 1295L, 
1291L, 1284L, 1125L, 1176L, 1214L, 1206L, 1216L, 1232L, 1234L, 
1268L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1326L, 1284L, 1265L, 
1237L, 1206L, 1212L, 1197L, 1181L, 1216L, 1222L, 1205L, 1148L, 
1163L, 1154L, 1138L, 1146L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1250L, 1229L, 1209L, 1199L, 1165L, 1191L, 1145L, 1130L, 1116L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1101L, NA, 1113L, 1126L, 1138L, 
1160L, 1128L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1155L, 1132L, 
1122L, 1146L, 1145L, 1146L, 1171L, 1103L, 1170L, 1136L, 1177L, 
1108L, 1106L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1175L, 1192L, 
1129L, 1163L, 1187L, 1177L, 1162L, 1184L, 1129L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1221L, 1113L, 1089L, 1099L, 1022L, 995L, 
947L, 1012L, 1065L, 1114L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1163L, 1094L, 1098L, 1139L, 1130L, 1117L, 1087L, 1084L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1137L, 1145L, 1130L, 1105L, 1123L, 
1112L, 1048L, 1055L, 1078L, 1147L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1207L, 1164L, 1169L, 1188L, 1189L, 1140L, 1099L, 1178L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1208L, NA, 1258L, 1207L, 1158L, 
1140L, 1099L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1123L, 1083L, 
1043L, 1066L, 1082L, 1049L, 1040L, 1090L, 1112L, 1069L, 1079L, 
1061L, 1029L, 1032L, 1046L, 1170L, 1197L, 956L, 941L, 1076L, 
1136L, 1208L, 1213L, 1207L, 1186L, 1225L, 1222L, 1232L, 1169L, 
1102L, 1144L, 1178L, 1218L, 1211L, 1229L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1255L, 1260L, 1236L, 1271L, 1312L, 1346L, 1272L, 
1171L, 1192L, 1235L, 1296L), Modulo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 44L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 26L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 43L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 27L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 39L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 42L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
18L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 29L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 40L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 41L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
22L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 30L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 16L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 33L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 34L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
37L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 38L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 31L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 32L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 35L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 36L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 25L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c(" ", "26=12mod6", "36=16mod4", "36=32mod4", 
"40=33mod8", "40=36mod2", "42=12mod6", "46=34mod6", "47=44mod2", 
"50=20mod4", "55=20mod4", "57=15mod6", "58=52mod4", "59=57mod2", 
"63=33mod4", "64=24mod8", "65=35mod6", "65=51mod6", "66=61mod6", 
"68=26mod6", "71=21mod6", "71=31mod4", "74=53mod8", "77=53mod4", 
"77=69mod2", "78=75mod4", "79=67mod6", "80=40mod4", "85=65mod4", 
"86=50mod8", "89=32mod2", "89=35mod2", "89=49mod4", "90=50mod6", 
"93=13mod8", "94=43mod4", "94=61mod4", "96=54mod4", "96=82mod6", 
"97=75mod2", "98=76mod2", "99=85mod8", "99=91mod8", "99=93mod6"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-997L))
```

Comment: This is quite a complex data-wrangling process. Do you only have one ACC_* code and one RT_* code per trial, or can they be multiple?

Comment: Yes, it's quite complicated and it go way beyond my abilities in R...
And yes I only have one ACC and one RT code per trial as it represent the accuracy and the response time of this trial. I have a 2000 Hz eye tracker that's why I have such a big file.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is to split your lines into buckets of all the same trial, then pull out the metadata vs data lines, and make them into a dataframe (assuming that's what you ultimately want).

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

# You may be reading this in with `readLines` or similar,
#   in which case you may not need to split on "\n" below

eye_text <- 
"Event; Info; Pupil size

Message; Start_trial_0;
Fixation; L; 1020
Fixation; L; 1200
Fixation; L; 980
Fixation; L; 990
Fixation; L; 1003
Message; Trial_0;
Message; ACC_1;
Message; RT_850;
Message; Stop_trial_0;
Message; Start_trial_1;
Fixation; L; 1023
Fixation; L; 1020
Fixation; L; 997
Fixation; L; 1123
Message; Trial_1;
Message; ACC_1;
Message; RT_920;
Message; Stop_trial_1;
Message; Start_trial_2;"  # Fixed typo?
```

---

```
# Depending how you read in the data, may already be a vector of lines
eye_lines <- str_split(eye_text, "\n")[[1]]

# Figure out where each trial starts
eye_starts <- cumsum(str_detect(eye_lines, "Start"))
```

## Split the data

`str_detect(eye_lines, "Start")` gives you a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` indicating the start of each trial. `cumsum` coerces that to `1`/`0` and takes the running total. This way you end up with `0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3`, or four groups from the sample text (the header, Trial 0, Trial 1, and one line of Trial 2).

---

```
eye_parser <- function(strings) {
  message_indices <- str_detect(strings, "Message;") & !str_detect(strings, "Start|Stop")

  messages <- 
    strings[message_indices] %>% 
    str_remove_all("Message; ") %>% 
    str_c(collapse = " ")

  if (length(messages) == 0) return(NULL)

  observations <- strings[!str_detect(strings, "Message")]

  str_c(messages, observations, sep = " ")
}
```

Here we subset the strings twice: first we get all the `Message;` lines (but not the `Start*`/`Stop*` lines), then we get all the non-`Message;` lines.

1. For the messages, we strip out "Message; ", which leaves you with the metadata values (a vector of `"Trial_0;", "ACC_1;", ...` etc). Then you `str_c` those all back together into a single metadata line: `"Trial_0; ACC_1; RT_850;"`.

   - At this point if the messages are all empty (like the header and partial trial), we just return `NULL`.
2. For the observations, we just take them as is. Then we `str_c` the messages and observations together, repeating `messages` in front of every observation line.

To use this function, we first split all your lines into the groups from above, then `purrr::map` the function over each group of strings. `unlist` takes it from a list of vectors to a single vector, and then `str_split(..., "; ", simplify = T)` breaks it out into a character matrix with columns. Finally `as.data.frame` makes it into a dataframe.

---

```
split(eye_lines, eye_starts) %>% 
  map(eye_parser) %>% 
  unlist(use.names = F) %>% 
  str_split("; ", simplify = T) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

> ```
>        V1    V2     V3       V4 V5   V6
> 1 Trial_0 ACC_1 RT_850 Fixation  L 1020
> 2 Trial_0 ACC_1 RT_850 Fixation  L 1200
> 3 Trial_0 ACC_1 RT_850 Fixation  L  980
> 4 Trial_0 ACC_1 RT_850 Fixation  L  990
> 5 Trial_0 ACC_1 RT_850 Fixation  L 1003
> 6 Trial_1 ACC_1 RT_920 Fixation  L 1023
> 7 Trial_1 ACC_1 RT_920 Fixation  L 1020
> 8 Trial_1 ACC_1 RT_920 Fixation  L  997
> 9 Trial_1 ACC_1 RT_920 Fixation  L 1123
> ```

---

## Caveats:

If your metadata isn't always exactly "Trial", "ACC", "RT" in that order, you'll probably want to extract those specifically. You can use the same code pattern I used for `messages` but for each of those individually. Then you can make sure they're present and in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian, it looks like a good solution, the thing is that I'm struggling with the first step, str_split and str_detect return me an error : "argument is not an atomic vector: coercing"

My first lines of code being :

`S1_data <- read.csv(file = "D:/Stim ST & ET/data/S1_data_t.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")`

`S1_data_filter <- S1_data %>% select(1,2,3,4,5,6,9)`

Comment: @Jibs I would say don't use `read.csv`. You need to read in the lines as strings in order to split them yourself. Try `readLines` (and then you can skip splitting on `"\n"`). I'm a little confused by how you're selecting multiple columns (1-6,9) from your raw data though, which seems to only have 3.

Comment: Oh ok. I was thinking that it was probably a problem in reading each row as a vector but didn't know how to fix this. For the multiple columns selection, it's coming from an older version where I kept the eye position too. Now I only want the pupil size.

Comment: Hi Brian, hope you still in there. The readlines works better than read.csv you were right. I now have an issue with the last split function. It returns me an error message:

Warning message:
In split.default(eye_lines, eye_starts) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable

Comment: Actually I don't know what to do with the ````eye_lines <- str_split(eye_text, "\n")[[1]]```` line.

Comment: Actually I don't know what to do with the ````eye_lines <- str_split(eye_text, "\n")[[1]]```` line.

Edit: I found out how to do, now the whole script work but I don't find where is the final data frame created at the end...

Comment: Ok an other comment (sorry for the multi-comment by the way). The script works but there's just few things that don't work properly. First, instead of returning the trial number, it returns the row number of the trial, e.g. the first trial has the value 68 in the "Trial" column, the 2nd trial has the value 119, etc.

Comment: @Jibs, it sounds like you're having some formatting issues since your actual data didn't look quite like your sample data here. Can you post a more representative example of your data?

Comment: Sure, I'll post a new answer with a sample of my dataset. I didn't think that would be this tricky to deal with that's why I posted first a simplify dataset.

Answer (score 0):

[Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57298245/7856717) has offered a perfect approach to your problem. My approach was slightly different, yet with similar results. For the sake of completion and/or variety i am going to post it though.

My way of thinking is as follows:

You first read in your file and pass it into a dataframe `df`

```
library(dplyr) # load the libraries we are going to be using first
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

df <- read.csv('~/Desktop/test', sep = ';', header = T) # I named your .txt file test here and put it on my Desktop
>df
      Event           Info Pupil.size
1   Message  Start_trial_0         NA
2  Fixation              L       1020
3  Fixation              L       1200
4  Fixation              L        980
5  Fixation              L        990
6  Fixation              L       1003
7   Message        Trial_0         NA
8   Message          ACC_0         NA
9   Message         RT_850         NA
10  Message   Stop_trial_0         NA
11  Message  Start_trial_1         NA
12 Fixation              L       1023
13 Fixation              L       1020
14 Fixation              L        997
15 Fixation              L       1123
16  Message        Trial_1         NA
17  Message          ACC_1         NA
18  Message         RT_920         NA
19  Message   Stop_trial_1         NA
20  Message  Strat_trial_2         NA
```

Then we create a new column, named **trial** where for every row on **Info** that has the trial info (the Start and Stop in this case), we pass the corresponding trial, otherwise we fill with `NA`, as such:

**Option 1** (original file data):

```
df <- df %>% mutate(trial=ifelse(Event=='Message'&grepl('trial', df$Info), gsub('.*_(trial_\\d)$', '\\1', df$Info), NA))
      Event           Info Pupil.size   trial
1   Message  Start_trial_0         NA trial_0
2  Fixation              L       1020    <NA>
3  Fixation              L       1200    <NA>
4  Fixation              L        980    <NA>
5  Fixation              L        990    <NA>
6  Fixation              L       1003    <NA>
7   Message        Trial_0         NA    <NA>
8   Message          ACC_0         NA    <NA>
9   Message         RT_850         NA    <NA>
10  Message   Stop_trial_0         NA trial_0
11  Message  Start_trial_1         NA trial_1
12 Fixation              L       1023    <NA>
13 Fixation              L       1020    <NA>
14 Fixation              L        997    <NA>
15 Fixation              L       1123    <NA>
16  Message        Trial_1         NA    <NA>
17  Message          ACC_1         NA    <NA>
18  Message         RT_920         NA    <NA>
19  Message   Stop_trial_1         NA trial_1
20  Message  Strat_trial_2         NA trial_2
```

**Option 2** (new input file - keep in mind this preserves the in-between trial data that you might want to get rid of):

```
df <- df %>% mutate(trial=ifelse(Event=='MSG'&grepl('trial', df$Info), gsub('.*_(trial_\\d)$', '\\1', df$Info), 
                                 ifelse(Event=='MSG'&grepl('consigne', df$Info), gsub('.*_(consigne)$', '\\1', df$Info),
                                        NA)))
```

I am filling with `NA` since on the next step we want to replace NAs with the earliest previous non `NA` value (thus assigning the correct trial on every row between the Start-Stop). This can be done with `na.locf` from the package `zoo`.

```
df$trial <- na.locf(df$trial)
> df
      Event           Info Pupil.size   trial
1   Message  Start_trial_0         NA trial_0
2  Fixation              L       1020 trial_0
3  Fixation              L       1200 trial_0
4  Fixation              L        980 trial_0
5  Fixation              L        990 trial_0
6  Fixation              L       1003 trial_0
7   Message        Trial_0         NA trial_0
8   Message          ACC_0         NA trial_0
9   Message         RT_850         NA trial_0
10  Message   Stop_trial_0         NA trial_0
11  Message  Start_trial_1         NA trial_1
12 Fixation              L       1023 trial_1
13 Fixation              L       1020 trial_1
14 Fixation              L        997 trial_1
15 Fixation              L       1123 trial_1
16  Message        Trial_1         NA trial_1
17  Message          ACC_1         NA trial_1
18  Message         RT_920         NA trial_1
19  Message   Stop_trial_1         NA trial_1
20  Message  Strat_trial_2         NA trial_2
```

We can now get rid of the rows with Trial "metadata" on the Info column.

```
df <- df %>% filter(!grepl('[T,t]rial', df$Info))
```

Next, we need the final "metadata" information per trial, namely ACC and RT information. These information are all within the Info column so we have to pull them out somehow. To do that first, we create two new columns named ACC and RT.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(ACC=ifelse(grepl('ACC', df$Info), as.character(df$Info), NA),
              RT=ifelse(grepl('RT', df$Info), as.character(df$Info), NA))

> df
      Event    Info Pupil.size   trial    ACC      RT
1  Fixation       L       1020 trial_0   <NA>    <NA>
2  Fixation       L       1200 trial_0   <NA>    <NA>
3  Fixation       L        980 trial_0   <NA>    <NA>
4  Fixation       L        990 trial_0   <NA>    <NA>
5  Fixation       L       1003 trial_0   <NA>    <NA>
6   Message   ACC_0         NA trial_0  ACC_0    <NA>
7   Message  RT_850         NA trial_0   <NA>  RT_850
8  Fixation       L       1023 trial_1   <NA>    <NA>
9  Fixation       L       1020 trial_1   <NA>    <NA>
10 Fixation       L        997 trial_1   <NA>    <NA>
11 Fixation       L       1123 trial_1   <NA>    <NA>
12  Message   ACC_1         NA trial_1  ACC_1    <NA>
13  Message  RT_920         NA trial_1   <NA>  RT_920
```

We also need to make sure which ACC and RT attributes correspond to each trial. For that purpose we create two new small dataframes via `dplyr` that give us all the ACC and RT info.

```
infoACC <- df %>% group_by(trial, Info) %>% summarize() %>% filter(grepl('ACC', Info))

> infoACC
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   trial [2]
  trial   Info    
  <chr>   <fct>   
1 trial_0 " ACC_0"
2 trial_1 " ACC_1"

infoRT <- df %>% group_by(trial, Info) %>% summarize() %>% filter(grepl('RT', Info))

> infoRT
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   trial [2]
  trial   Info     
  <chr>   <fct>    
1 trial_0 " RT_850"
2 trial_1 " RT_920"
```

Then it's just a matter of joining our df and the two new dataframes to get the ACC and RT info in, dropping the additional columns and left-over rows (Message rows)

```
df <- left_join(left_join(df, infoACC, by='trial'), infoRT, by='trial') %>% select(-ACC, -RT) %>% filter(!Event=='Message')
```

And wrap this up with fixing up the column names.

```
colnames(df) <- c('Event', 'Info', 'Pupil.size', 'Trial', 'ACC', 'RT')
> df
     Event Info Pupil.size   Trial    ACC      RT
1 Fixation    L       1020 trial_0  ACC_0  RT_850
2 Fixation    L       1200 trial_0  ACC_0  RT_850
3 Fixation    L        980 trial_0  ACC_0  RT_850
4 Fixation    L        990 trial_0  ACC_0  RT_850
5 Fixation    L       1003 trial_0  ACC_0  RT_850
6 Fixation    L       1023 trial_1  ACC_1  RT_920
7 Fixation    L       1020 trial_1  ACC_1  RT_920
8 Fixation    L        997 trial_1  ACC_1  RT_920
9 Fixation    L       1123 trial_1  ACC_1  RT_920
```

You can now save this as a new .csv or keep it as a dataframe for further operations in R.

I admit its a bit of a more complicated solution, but i wanted to offer my thinking process hoping to show you that there are many ways to approach your problems in R and you can tackle your questions in a stepwise manner.

Comment: Hi Steve,

Thanks a lot for your reply. It is a good solution too. It starts good but when replacing NAs with na.locf, it throw me an error; replacement has 939 rows, data has 997.

I think I have found the problem. In my data, I have some inter-trial pupil size measures. So the NAs bteween each trial may be the problem.

I not sure how to fix this.

Comment: I see your point. Are there any distinguishing characteristics for those rows perhaps? Like Message;Mid-trial? or something that we can use to first fix these rows and then run na.locf?

Comment: Unfortunately there no difference between inter trial lines and the trial ones. They just look the same... Do you think it will be possible to exclude them? Like if they are after a stop and before a start?

Comment: Yes, that we could do. Can you add a dput() output containing that part?

Comment: Is dput() is for you to be able to read or have an overview of it data frame? Is it returning me a file or something I can return to you? I'll do that!

Comment: No worries at all! dput() output is something i can copy and paste in my R environment and immediately have the same data structure you have. See more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/7856717)

Comment: Sorry for the time it took, I was out with the kids ^^

Here is the result of the dput() function on my data set (see in the next answer):

Comment: Hey Jibs! I am taking a look at your `dput` output. Are you sure this is all? It should start with `structure(....` , but i don't see it here and cant load it in.

Comment: Hi Steve, I should have done it wrong the first time, I added the ````dput()```` output in a new comment and now it starts by ````structure(...````

Comment: Alright, so i've detected why you get the error. At the beginning of your dput() -this is different than your original table though -  you have some parameters not part of a trial but part of "consigne". I've classified these as well now with Option 2 on my original post. However this preserves the inter-trial data observations which you'd like (?) to get rid off.

Comment: Ok Steve, you're now officially my new hero ! It works just fine now. The inter-trial observations are not a problem as they might be informative for us. And if not, I can modify my experiment script to exclude them. 
Thanks a lot for your time ! You werre very helpfull !

Comment: Glad i could help:) I really liked Brian's solution, especially on the part of getting your meta.data out, so a combination of the two methods/answers is probably your best bet. Good luck and keep up the good work!

Comment: Yes his solution is really nice too. I would like to make it work too ! The program kind of works but it returns me really weird data-frame in the end. I'm sure it's a little thing to fix so I'm still trying. But otherwise, your solution works just fine ^^
Thank you again and sorry for my english if it's not perfect because I'm french.